# CF 10 generated spreadsheet shows date as text

Tags: excel, coldfusion

Team - Any idea on how to get the date format right in the excel file generated through Coldfusion from a database query. Following is the partial code

```
   <cfset formathr = structnew()/>
   <cfset formathr.bold = "true"/>
   <cfset formathr.alignment = "center"/>
   <cfset formathr.bottomborder = "double"/>
   <cfset formathr.fgcolor = "pale_blue"/>
   <cfset formattotr = structnew()>
   <cfset formattotr1 = structnew()>
   <cfset format = structnew()>
   <cfset formatdatecolumn = structnew()>
   <cfset formatdatecolumn.dataformat = "mm/dd/yyyy"/>
   <cfset formattotr.alignment = "center"/>
   <cfset formattotr.topborder = "double"/>

    <cfset sobj = SpreadSheetNew("true")/>

   <cfset SpreadsheetAddrow(sobj,"id,name,team,datejoined,dateretired,amount, maintaincost, noyears")/>
    <cfset SpreadsheetFormatRow(sobj, formathr,"1")/>            
    <cfset SpreadsheetAddRows(sobj, QryName)/>
    <cfset formattotr1.dataformat = "##,##0"/>`enter code here`
    <cfset SpreadsheetFormatColumn(sobj, formatdatecolumn, "4-5")/>
```

Tried quite a few options suggested here and elsewhere, still no luck.

**Update:**

I realized dates can be blank in my case and hence I'm having issues with the format. The following is from my query

```
 CASE 
      WHEN e.DateRetired=0 THEN NULL 
      ELSE TO_CHAR( TO_DATE('01-01-1970','DD-MM-YY') + ( e.DateRetired/ 86400000 )
                    , 'MM/DD/YYYY'
               ) 
 END AS DateRetired
```

Comment: I'd use dateformat() to convert them all to strings.

Comment: What is your full CF version?

Comment: version 10 patch level 19

Comment: Try this code http://trycf.com/gist/3ba2202e26067ea45bc184993b7f756c/acf?theme=monokai

Comment: FWIW, the code above worked fine for me with 10.0.19 assuming the query columns "DateRetired" and "DateJoined" are type datetime. Though I think you meant to use `SpreadsheetFormatColumns` (plural) instead of `SpreadsheetFormatColumn` (singular).

Comment: the code works fine with the example you gave -Thanks -  i realized dates can be blank in my case and hence i'm having issues with the format. following is from my query
  CASE WHEN e.DateRetired=0 THEN NULL ELSE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-01-1970','DD-MM-YY') + ( e.DateRetired/ 86400000 ), 'MM/DD/YYYY') END AS DateRetired,

Comment: Since you ultimately want Excel to do the formatting, you should not need to format in the SQL as well. The problem with using `TO_CHAR()` is that while it produces the format you want, it returns a "string", rather than a date object (which IIRC, is what is required for CF/POI to apply the date formatting correctly). What happens if you change the SQL and return type "date" instead?

Comment: If to_char is giving you a string in the correct format and that's good enough, don't try to format it it further.

Comment: @DanBracuk - True, but I assume they would not have posed the question if treating the value "as text" was good enough ;-) Unfornately Excel performs a lot of extra interpretations and/or transformations behind the scenes. Naturally you might expect CF spreadsheet functions to behave the same way, but they often don't. Achieving the same effect usually requires being more explicit and sensitive to data types. Especially prior to CF11.